# How to insert google addsese into MySQL database using PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert Google Addsense code into Mysql database using php mysql in the live Linux server. But its not inserted, actually Google Addsense code inserted into my local Mysql database in my local system, but not in the server. ***Since Google Addsense code is a javascript code, may be due to this its not inserted(Normal data inserted),*** please help me how to insert such type of data into database.

Comment: `mysql_`, `mysqli_` or `PDO` ? Show us your code...it will be easier :)

Comment: I am using mysql_ , simple PHP code using, just created one textarea and submit the form, fetch the form data with POST method and applying insert method..(Normal data inserted) if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $adsname  = $_POST['adsname'];
  mysql_query("insert into addads(adsname) values('$adsname')") or die(mysql_errno());
  
}

Comment: That sounds like a simple probem with quotes or something... Can we see code? Help us help you...

Comment: <form name="frm" method="post" action="addads.php">
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div><textarea cols="8" rows="8" name="adsname" id="adsname"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></div>
    
</div></form> if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $adsname  = $_POST['adsname'];
  mysql_query("insert into addads(adsname) values('$adsname')") or die(mysql_errno());
  
}

Answer (score 0):

> Addsense code inserted into my local Mysql database in my local
>   system, but not in the server

Looks like you connected to database on your local machine instead of wanted server.

Acording to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

`mysql_connect('<<<IP ADDDRESS TO YOUR SERVER>>>', '<<<USERNAME>>>', '<<<PASSWORD>>>');`

Comment: Hi thanks, but the complete site working properly but when insert the Google Addsense code its not inserted into database instead of, site is redirected to the main domain.